# Using Subtraction in a Conditional Statement in Verilog

Tags: conditional-statements, verilog

I'm relatively new to Verilog and I've been working on a project in which I would, in an ideal world, like to have an assignment statement like:

```
assign isinbufferzone = a > (packetlength-16384) ? 1:0;
```

The file with this type of line in it will compile, but `isinbufferzone` doesn't go high when it should. I'm assuming it's not happy with having subtraction in the conditional. I'm able to make the module work by moving stuff around, but the result is more complicated than I think it should need to be and the latency really starts to add up. Does anyone have any thoughts on what the most concise way to do this is? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: `x ? 1 : 0` is just `x`.

Comment: How are `isinbufferzone`, `a` and `packetlength` declared?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Isinbufferzone is a wire and a and packetlength are 17 bit width regs

Comment: I tried this in iverilog.com online simulator and it works. Arithmetic within conditional statements work just fine. Maybe do the subtraction right before this statement and see if that works without much latency?

Comment: @Qazi Sure, the subtraction works, but it overflows if `packetlength` is less than 16384.

Comment: Example: Paste from [here](https://codepaste.net/9myuqe) into iverilog.com

Comment: Thanks, it's good to know that that exists, it'll definitely help me in the future when I'm questioning the syntax I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably expect `isinbufferzone` to go high if `packetlength` is 16384 or less regardless of `a`, however this is not what happens.

If `packetlength` is less than 16384, the value `packetlength - 16384` is not a negative number −*X*, but some very large positive number (maybe 2<sup>32</sup> − *X*, or 2<sup>17</sup> − *X*, I'm not quite sure which, but it doesn't matter), because Verilog does unsigned arithmetic by default. This is called [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

You could maybe try to solve this by declaring some signals as `signed`, but in my opinion the safest way is to explicitly handle the overflow case and making sure the subtraction result is only evaluated for `packetlength` values of 16384 or greater:

```
assign isinbufferzone = (packetlength < 16384) ? 1 : (a > packetlength - 16384);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, this ended up answering my question really well. I guess I'm learning pretty quickly that if I think there's a syntax error, it's probably actually a conceptual issue with the design.